# Validate command string in hexa decimal format with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I will receive a command parameter string in the format "%04hx %04hx". Sample command parameter string is "09EC 000A".

I need to check whether the data format is valid. I have tried to check whether the parameter string is valid with the following format string

"%[0123456789abcdefABCDEF ]s".  This format will work even when multiple spaces are there between hexadecimal numbers and leading spaces are there.

Is it possible to check whether the command parameter string has only two 4 digit hexadecimal numbers with a space between them with sscanf?

Manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf` probably cannot easily do this. Either use regular expressions or write your own validation function:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int is_valid (const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 4; i++) if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) return 0;
    /* change the next line to (s[i++]!=' ') if wanted */
    if (!isspace((unsigned char)s[i++])) return 0; 
    for(; i < 9; i++) if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `tolower()` not needed in `isxdigit(tolower(s[i]))`.  `isxdigit()` accepts 0-9, A-F, a-f.  Better to cast to `unsigned char` as `isxdigit(), tolower()` not deifned for negative fails other than `EOF`.  --> `if (!isxdigit((unsigned char) s[i] )) return 0;`

Comment: @chux Good point. However, since `s` is presumably an ASCII string, all characters would be in the range 0-127.

Comment: Reasonable to assume `s` is composed of only ASCII characters.  Yet OP is looking for validation, presumable to detect errors.  One error type could well be detecting non-ASCII characters.

Comment: "The  values  returned  are  nonzero if the character c falls into the tested class, and a zero value if not." So, no, there is no need to cast. In fact, `isxdigit()` takes a signed int, just like all other `is...` macros.

Comment: Disagree about need for cast.  7.4 Character handling <ctype.h>  "In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undeﬁned. "  When `s[i]` is < 0 and not `EOF`, the result is UB.  The ctype.h functions are only defined for values  `[0...UCHAR_MAX], EOF`. rest is UB.

Comment: @chux There is a disagreement between the manual page and the standard. So, ok, cast it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to check whether the command parameter string has only two 4 digit hexadecimal numbers with a space between them with sscanf?

Yes, check each character and save the character scanned count with `"%n"`.

```
  // notice no 's' at the end
  #define HEX1 "%*1[0123456789abcdefABCDEF]"
  // the '*' directs sscanf() to not save the result.
  #define SPC1 "%*1[ ]"

  char *sample = "09EC 000A";
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(sample, HEX1 HEX1 HEX1 HEX1 SPC1 HEX1 HEX1 HEX1 HEX1 "%n", &n);
  if (n && sample[n] == 0) {
    puts("Success");
  } else {
    puts("Fail");
  }
```

or maybe use the return value of `sscanf()` and detect trailing character with a sentinel.

```
  char hex[2][5] = { 0 };
  char sentinel;
  #define HEX "%1[0123456789abcdefABCDEF]"
  //#define SPC1 "%*1[ ]"
  if (8 == sscanf(sample, HEX HEX HEX HEX SPC1 HEX HEX HEX HEX "%c",
      &hex[0][0], &hex[0][1], &hex[0][2], &hex[0][3],
      &hex[1][0], &hex[1][1], &hex[1][2], &hex[1][3],
      &sentinel)) {
    printf("Success %s %s\n", hex[0], hex[1]);
  } else {
    puts("Fail");
  }
```

or maybe something less verbose

```
  #define HEX4 "%4[0123456789abcdefABCDEF]"
  sscanf(sample, HEX4 SPC1 HEX4 "%n", hex[0], hex[1], &n);
  if (n == 9 && sample[n] == 0) {
    printf("Success %s %s\n", hex[0], hex[1]);
  } else {
    puts("Fail");
  }
```

Direct use of `"%x"` allows for optionally leading white space characters.  Could use `"%n"` to detect.  Yet `"%x"` allows `"0x12"`, `"+123"`, `"-123"`, which is not invalided with the below.

```
  int m[4] = { 0 };
  unsigned cmd[2];
  sscanf(sample, " %n%x%n" SPC1 " %n%x%n",
      &m[0], &cmd[0], &m[1],
      &m[2], &cmd[1], &m[3]);
  if (m[0] == 0 && m[1] == 4 && m[2] == 5 && m[3] == 9 && sample[m[3]] == 0) {
    printf("Success %04x %04x\n", cmd[0], cmd[1]);
  } else {
    puts("Fail");
  }
```

Many possibilities.